# How to create an android project using the command line?

Tags: android, command-line

I tried creating a project using android (https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html) but this tool is deprecated.
Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: When you can a complete project manually by fooling around in Android Studio, why do you need to create it using a Command Line?

Comment: @Avid When you can create a project with the CLI, why do you need to download and install Android Studio?